# Vue route with dynamic import causes default layout to flash for split of second

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm using Vue 3 with vue-router and vite-plugin-pages, which by default loads all route components asynchronously.

I have made a simple layout component which switches between `LayoutDefault` and `LayoutBlank`, based on the route's meta. Blank is only for public sites like the login page, where user is not yet logged in. I made it this way so I only need to set the layout on few routes instead of all of them.

Because of the dynamic import though, when entering the site and being redirected to the login site via router's `beforeEach` guard, you can see the default layout being drawn for a split of a second and then switches to blank layout. This happens, because `route.meta.layout` in the watcher is always undefined at the beginning.

I could make `/login` to load synchronously, but I don't like this approach as I might be adding more "public" routes that should render in `LayoutBlank`, and same glitch also happens on them even when entering directly and not being redirected by the router.

Is there any fix to this other than switching the order of layouts so blank is default or loading everything synchronously? I tried to use another `beforeEach` hook instead of watching `route.meta.layout` but all it did, was moving the glitch to route leaving instead of entering when layouts were switched.

I couldn't use Vue3 in snippet so I put a simple demo code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-router-meta-layout-spc5tq?file=src%2Flayouts%2FAppLayout.vue,src%2Frouter.ts

When you reload the web container, you will notice the red "Default Layout" text flicker.

Some code:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import AppLayoutDefault from './AppLayoutDefault.vue'
import AppLayoutBlank from './AppLayoutBlank.vue'
import { markRaw, ref, watch } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const layout = ref()
const route = useRoute()

watch(
  () => route.meta?.layout as string | undefined,
  (metaLayout) => {
    layout.value = markRaw(metaLayout === 'blank' ? AppLayoutBlank : AppLayoutDefault)
  },
  { immediate: true }
)
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="layout"> <router-view /> </component>
</template>
```

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      component: () => import('@/views/Login.vue'),
      meta: { layout: 'blank', public: true },
    },
    {
      path: '/admin',
      component: () => import('@/views/Admin.vue'),
      meta: { layout: 'AppLayoutAdmin' },
    },
  ],
})

let isLoggedIn = false
router.beforeEach((to) => {
  if (!to.meta.public && !isLoggedIn) {
    isLoggedIn = true

    return 'login'
  }
})

export default router
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your html template page to have the same background as your target page, in combination with beforeEach?

Comment: @StevenSpungin well it's not just about the background, in my app the default layout renders the content in a container surrounded by the navigation bar. I have simplified the problem in the example, but in my app I can see the navigation bar flicker and then the login form appear, which looks pretty bad

Answer (score 2):

I have actually found an answer! It was caused by most examples on the internet not ever mentioning `router.isReady()`! I was curious why `route.fullPath` returned `/` on every page load, even when entering `/login`. This led me to this snippet:

```js
router.isReady().then(() => app.mount())
```

And guess what, delaying `app.mount()` like that actually fixed my whole problem. Now the first layout that is rendered is actually the one configured in the route, even if it's not the default one.

Comment: where do you add the isReady to? can you update stackbiz demo on the top?